# make function to change password

Tags: java, algorithm, backbone.js, architecture

I am a beginner in web programming and I need to create function to change password like in social network. I'm doing it first time and don't know how to do it. I don't know how to create architecture. I'm using **backbone.js** in user side, I will  create  *userModel* (this is backbone model). In server side I'm  using **Java**. I have one idea that: add to UserClass (this is java class) new fields which named

```
@JsonIgnore
String oldPassword;

@JsonIgnore
String newPassword;
```

*JsonIgnore* make field invisible on user side. I will send the fields  with *userModel* from user side,so I check in server side. I think, the idea is not good. 
If You know any ways, please, tell me about it !

**EDIT**

I know how to make html-form. I don't know how to send the filds to server. If I do that:

```
var val1 // old_pass
var val2 // new_pass
this.model.save({password: val1,new_password: val2});
```

then model password change to val1, it is not correct, password do not set in user side, because user side haven't model password

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you know how to do anything else? Did you already create a login page? Or a page for registering new users? A use case like "changing a password" is rather unusual to start with if you are a total beginner.

Comment: Yes, I already did what You ask. All work ok.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your server authentication process work but maybe you can try something like this. Create a new View with a `user model` inside to edit the user attributes. Inside that view render a form that displays the user attributes including the passwords. On the form the user will be able to change his information. Have a button called "Save" or something like that to store the changes. When the button is clicked create a function that grabs the values from the form and using the model `save` method. This method makes Backbone run a PUT command back to the server. On the server you should be able to handle this request and change the password. A very simple function you can write to save the changes in the view could be something like this:

```
changePassword = function() {
 var attributes;
 attributes = {
  password: $('#password').val(),
  confirm_password: $('#confirm_password').val()
 };
 this.model.save(attributes);
};
```

This functions will create an attributes object filled with the password fields and then it sends it back to the server. If you want to understand a little bit more about how the `save` method work you should check the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save). Hope this helps!

Comment: thank You for advice, I did what You say, but this way is considered to be wrong

Comment: Why do you say that is considered to be wrong? Here you are just structuring your code to send the correct user information back to the server. Of course there are a lot of security immplementations that you should add, but I just wanted to get you started.

Comment: I meant by **considered to be wrong** that if send values with model, model `set` the attributes, then the model will do `save`. I need to send without `set` old password and new password, then in server side check the values